# htaccess solving duplicate get variable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having problem with htaccess in which I want to have the same method of index.php?p='$_GET['page']' to apply for my account.php?username='$_GET['username']' in the same website. This is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^inc/.*$ index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^inc/.*$ index.php?p=account.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ index.php?p=account.php&username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I want the url in my page to be similar or the same like this:

> www.composeplus.com/page

and when user logged in and access to their account name it should be like this:

> www.composeplus.com/username

or

> www.composeplus.com/account/username

Does anyone have the solution for me? thanks

Comment: Basicly its on you what kind of URL you deliver, the only thing you need is bootstrap each route to index.php. So if the user is logged in, show only links with that start with `www.composeplus.com/account/username` Your .htaccess first part seems ok, second part is not needed.

Comment: But when I try www.composeplus.com/account/pagna (pagna is my username) it show:            **Not Found
The requested URL /composeplus.com/account/pagna was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.** When I use only the above code

Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.5.38 Server at localhost Port 80

Answer (score 0):

Let me have a try that makes my comment a little clearer.

Creat an .htaccess in the root-web folder of your server like

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?qwerty=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So now everthing that is not a real file will be redirect to `index.php` with the full URL as `qwerty=FOO/BAR`

In index.php you can know react on the given input.

Lets say you call `www.composeplus.com/account/username` it will redirect to `www.composeplus.com/index.php?qwertz=/account/username` and `www.composeplus.com/page` to `www.composeplus.com/index.php?qwertz=/page`

That is basicly how redirect work. Normaly a function in index.php will check `qwertz` and call the needed subfiles/classes depending on your api.

NOTE: It is an example, your stuff has `inc/` folder and i dont know for what that is.